# Manipulating with images pixel through binary

Tags: c++, binary, pixel

Is it possible to manipulate pixels of image ( e.g creating sepia , grayscale , resizing etc ) trought binary code ?

Lets say we open an image with

```
bool readFile(string filename) {

  ifstream f(filename, ios::binary | ios:: in );
  ostringstream ob;
  int offset = 0;
  char c;

  if (f.fail()) {

    return false;

  }

  while (f.get(c)) {

    if (offset % 16 == 0)
      cout << hex << setw(8) << setfill('0') << offset << "adress ";

    cout << ' ' << hex << setw(2) << (int)(unsigned char) c;

    offset++;

  }

  return true;
}

int main() {
  if (!readFile("boss.png")) {
    cout << "Cant read" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can we access images pixels using its binary representation? If so , how ? I fail to find good resource for this.

Comment: You surely can. [PNG is a public format.](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html)

Comment: I do it to JPEGs all the time.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with an image? Hide data in it? Create your own image codec?

Comment: I would like to ,as i said , create grayscale / sepia effect , compress it , or even hide data in it. I have only done all of that using pixels directly not trought binary

Answer (score 0):

[PNG is a well documented file format](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html), and thus, theoretically it's possible for you to manipulate the image data directly. However, this is rather unusual. Generally, you would convert it to an uncompressed format, manipulate it, and then recompress it into a PNG, because reading/writing uncompressed image data is much more straightforward (and, unless you're only reading/writing a few pixels, likely much faster).

A search turns up many examples of how to read/write PNG files, for example [here](https://gist.github.com/niw/5963798).